# Align environment

Tags: environments, align

I'd like to ask how in align environment to number only one of the equations.

```
\begin{aligned}
\mathsf{E}[W^{i}_{t}-W^{i}_{s}]&=0,\\
\mathsf{E}\big[[W^{i}_{t}-W^{i}_{s}][W^{j}_{t}-W^{j}_{s}]\big]&=q_{ij}(t-s),\quad
1\le i,j\le n,\, 0\le s<t.
\end{aligned}
```

One more question. (The first one has already been sorted out). How can I break page in the align environment?

Comment: Place a `\notag` command in each line that you do not wish numbered.

Comment: Also, your exampled uses the `aligned` environment, did you mean to use `align` instead?

Comment: Try `\allowdisplaybreaks` in the preamble to allow page breaks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `aligned` environment is a *subsidiary math environment* and thus can be used within another math environment. For example:

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\mathsf{E}[W^{i}_{t}-W^{i}_{s}]&=0,\\
\mathsf{E}\big[[W^{i}_{t}-W^{i}_{s}][W^{j}_{t}-W^{j}_{s}]\big]&=q_{ij}(t-s),\quad
1\le i,j\le n,\, 0\le s<t.
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
```

This automatically numbers the entire aligned group. But if you are just using it within `$ $` or `\[ \]` there is no numbering. Hence, to get the numbering right, rather use the the `align` environment as follows:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\mathsf{E}[W^{i}_{t}-W^{i}_{s}]&=0,\\
\mathsf{E}\big[[W^{i}_{t}-W^{i}_{s}][W^{j}_{t}-W^{j}_{s}]\big]&=q_{ij}(t-s),\quad
1\le i,j\le n,\, 0\le s<t. \notag \\
\mathsf{E}[W^{i}_{t}-W^{i}_{s}]&=0,
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Notice the employment of the `\notag` command to remove the numbering on desired lines.

This yields:

[image]

To work with the page breaks for the align environment, one can use `\allowdisplaybreaks`. For example:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[2-6]
{\allowdisplaybreaks
\begin{align}
\mathsf{E}[W^{i}_{t}-W^{i}_{s}]&=0,\\
\mathsf{E}\big[[W^{i}_{t}-W^{i}_{s}][W^{j}_{t}-W^{j}_{s}]\big]&=q_{ij}(t-s),\quad
1\le i,j\le n,\, 0\le s<t. \notag \\
\mathsf{E}[W^{i}_{t}-W^{i}_{s}]&=0,
\end{align}}
\end{document}
```

This gives:

[image]

Comment: @Jane You are most welcome. If you ever need further clarifications ask.

Comment: I do. I modified the question. as well, I would need to break page in the align environment.

Comment: Did `\allowdisplaybreaks` work for you? You can use it also in the form `{\allowdisplaybreaks **align content here**}`

Comment: No, it doesn't work. Maybe i don't use it in the right way. However, I would prefer an automatic solution.

Comment: @Jane See my update answer.:)

Comment: Well done it works now with the \allowdisplaybreaks in the preamble.